# why the values of properties in the prototype are inconsistent?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I called `console.log(Family.prototype.money)` and value is 200, which confirms that `asset` is the prototype of the function `Family`. But when I called `console.log(other.money)`, the value is 1000, which I assigned before to the prototype. What is wrong here? It looks like the prototype of the object other is different from that of the function Family, which totally contradicts with what I read from the book Object-Oriented Javascript.

```
        function Family(father, mother, children){
            this.father = father,
            this.mother = mother,
            this.children = children,
            this.num = function(){
                return (this.children.length+2);
            }

        }       


        Family.prototype.money = 1000; // notice!!!!

        var myFamily = new Family('Hung', 'Hong', ['Phuong', 'Lien', 'Hiep']);
        var other = new myFamily.constructor('Lan', 'Linh', ['Tung']);

        var money = other.money;

        var asset = {
            money: 200,
            car: 2,
            house: 10
        }
        Family.prototype = asset;
```

Comment: It does not contradict - you're replacing the object's prototype but other objects still have reference to the original prototype. Not sure why you think this operation must propagate.

Comment: `var a = 1, b = a; a = 2;` Do you expect now `b` to be `1` or `2`?

Comment: I cannot follow your question.

Comment: Don't bother about it. I asked because I though that the prototype of a function is the same as that of an instance object. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prototype` of a function is not the actual prototype of the instance object. When you use `new` the `prototype` object is used as a template for the internal `[[Prototype]]` property, exposed in some browsers as `__proto__`. So before you change the `prototype` this expression is `true`:

```
Family.prototype === other.__proto__ // true
Family.prototype = asset;
```

And after you chnge it, it is `false`:

```
Family.prototype = asset;
Family.prototype === other.__proto__ // false
```

Comment: can you tell me how to return the prototype of instance object?

Comment: it does not work. The console log return undefined when I calld console.log(other.prototype);

Comment: @PMH—instances have an internal `[[Prototype]]` property that references the object that was their constructor's public prototype at the time they were constructed. If you later change the constructor's prototype to a new object, existing instances still reference the old object. New instances will reference the new object. To get the instance `[[Prototype]]`, use ES5's [*Object.getPrototypeOf*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2). There is no equivalent in previous versions of the language, though *instance.constructor.prototype* may work (it's unreliable though).